# this application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

In iOS, I'm getting the following error :

"this application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread"

Does anybody know how to debug it?

EDIT1: Share my Code and Logs:

```
//
class AlertViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
@IBOutlet weak var token: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var alertTable: AlertTableVC!
@IBOutlet weak var alertTypeColl: AlertTypeCollection!

@IBOutlet weak var goHome: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var goNewAlert: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var goProfile: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var goNotifications: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var goMap: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var alertActions: UIView!
static let locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet var GestureGoNewAlert: UITapGestureRecognizer!



var x: String = "0.0"
var y: String = "0.0"
var tokenUser: String = ""
var userName: String = ""
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
var doSearchByLocation: Bool = true; // es falso cuando se hace pull to refresh dado que se encuentra buscando actualizaciones
var isFirstSearch: Bool = true;
static var isSearchByLocation: Bool = false;
var lastSearchDate:NSDate = NSDate()
var lastSearchCal: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
var pleaseWait: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message:"Registrando Percepción de la zona. \n\n\n", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //alertTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 20, 0);
    let bottomBorder = CALayer()
    let bgColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.827, green: 0.827, blue: 0.827, alpha: 1)
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.alertActions.frame.size.width, 0.5);
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = bgColor.CGColor
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refreshAlerts:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    alertTable.addSubview(refreshControl)
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(130.5, 85.5);
    spinner.color = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1);
    spinner.startAnimating();
    pleaseWait.view.addSubview(spinner)
    alertTable.vc = self
    alertTable.showGeoProfile = true
    alertTypeColl.alertController=self

    self.alertTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.alertTable.estimatedRowHeight = 160
    self.alertTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None


    //self.alertTypeColl.
     //self.AlertCommentsTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.alertActions.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
        self.goHome.titleLabel?.text = vooffKeys.homeIcon
        self.goHome.setTitle( vooffKeys.homeIcon, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.goNotifications.titleLabel?.text = vooffKeys.notificationIcon
        self.goNotifications.setTitle( vooffKeys.notificationIcon, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.goProfile.titleLabel?.text = vooffKeys.profileIcon
        self.goProfile.setTitle( vooffKeys.profileIcon, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.goNewAlert.titleLabel?.text = vooffKeys.newAlertIcon
        self.goNewAlert.setTitle( vooffKeys.newAlertIcon, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.goMap.titleLabel?.text = vooffKeys.mapAlertIcon
        self.goMap.setTitle( vooffKeys.mapAlertIcon, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    })

           //  firstName.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)*/
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    AlertViewController.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if let lastLoc = locations.last {
        let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = lastLoc.coordinate

        if AlertViewController.isSearchByLocation && self.x != String(locValue.longitude) && self.y != String(locValue.latitude){
            AlertViewController.isSearchByLocation = false
            self.x = String(locValue.longitude)
            self.y = String(locValue.latitude)
            // print("lat: \(locValue.latitude) lng: \(locValue.longitude)")
            let searchDate:NSDateComponents = lastSearchCal.components([NSCalendarUnit.Day , NSCalendarUnit.Month , NSCalendarUnit.Year , NSCalendarUnit.Hour , NSCalendarUnit.Minute , NSCalendarUnit.Second], fromDate: lastSearchDate)
            let searchDateStr = "\(String(format: "%02d", searchDate.day))-\(String(format: "%02d", searchDate.month))-\(searchDate.year)%20\(String(format: "%02d",searchDate.hour)).\(String(format: "%02d", searchDate.minute)).\(String(format: "%02d", searchDate.second))"
            self.isFirstSearch = false
            print (" .... locationManager ....")
            self.getAlerts (self.tokenUser, x: self.x, y: self.y, username:  self.userName , lastsearch: searchDateStr)


            lastSearchDate = NSDate()
            lastSearchCal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            //do_table_refresh()
            //crear una variable y setear la ultima vez que se busca por location

        }
    }
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {
    print (" .... locationManager fromLocation ....")
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print ("No se pudo obtener la ubicacion: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func refreshAlerts (refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    AlertViewController.isSearchByLocation = false;
    AlertViewController.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    self.getAlerts (self.tokenUser, x: self.x, y: self.y, username:  self.userName , lastsearch: "")
    lastSearchDate = NSDate()
    lastSearchCal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    //do_table_refresh()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    //print("estamos refrescando la info !!")
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    self.alertTable.delegate = self.alertTable
    self.alertTable.dataSource = self.alertTable
    self.alertTypeColl.delegate = self.alertTypeColl
    self.alertTypeColl.dataSource = self.alertTypeColl

    if  let userToken = userDefaults.objectForKey(vooffKeys.accessToken) {
        AlertViewController.isSearchByLocation = false
        if let userTokenStr: String = userToken as? String  {
            let userData = Functions.obtainUserData()
            self.userName =  userData[vooffKeys.profileUser]!
            self.tokenUser = userTokenStr
            RestApiManager.sharedInstance.setPushToken (self.tokenUser, username: self.userName, pushToken: userData[vooffKeys.pushToken]!, onCompletition:  { json -> Void in
                print ("Push notification seteado")
                print (json)
            })

         //   print ("TokenLogin: " + userTokenStr)
            AlertViewController.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            AlertViewController.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

                AlertViewController.locationManager.delegate = self
                AlertViewController.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
                AlertViewController.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                if let usrLoc = AlertViewController.locationManager.location {
                    self.x = String(usrLoc.coordinate.longitude)
                    self.y = String(usrLoc.coordinate.latitude)

                   // print ("locationServicesEnabled " + self.x + ";" + self.y)
                    self.getAlerts (self.tokenUser, x: self.x, y: self.y, username:  self.userName , lastsearch: "")
                    self.getAlertTypes(self.tokenUser, username:  self.userName )
            }

         }

        } else {
            print ("No se encontro str")
        }
    } else {
        print ("No se encontro en defaults: " + vooffKeys.accessToken)
    }

}

func getAlerts (token: String, x: String, y: String, username: String, lastsearch:String) {
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getAlerts(token, x: x, y: y, username: username, lastsearch: lastsearch, onCompletition: {json -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
         //  print(json)
            if json["hasAccess"] == nil || json["hasAccess"]["isValid"].boolValue {
                self.alertTable.userPos = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(Double(x)!), y: CGFloat(Double(y)!))
                if lastsearch != "" {
                    if var alertArray = self.alertTable.alertsData {
                        if let newArray = json.array {
                            alertArray.insertContentsOf(newArray, at: 1)
                            self.alertTable.alertsData = alertArray
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.alertTable.alertsData = [json]
                    }
                } else {

                    self.alertTable.alertsData = [json]
                }
                self.do_table_refresh()
            }
            else {
                if json["hasAccess"]["gotologin"].boolValue {
                    Functions.openLoginPage(self)
                }
            }
        })
       // print("Registros Encontrados:  \(json.array?.count) ")
    })
}

func do_table_refresh()    {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.alertTable.reloadData()
        //self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        return
    })
}
func getAlertTypes (token: String, username: String) {
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getAlertTypes(token, username: username, onCompletition: {json -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if json["hasAccess"] == nil || json["hasAccess"]["isValid"].boolValue {
                //print("Registros Encontrados:  \(json.array?.count) ")
                self.alertTypeColl.criminalTypes = [json]
                self.alertTypeColl.reloadData()
                //self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                return
            }
            else {
                if json["hasAccess"]["gotologin"].boolValue {
                    Functions.openLoginPage(self)
                }
            }
        })
    })
}

@IBAction func doGoNewAlert(sender: UIButton) {
    print("dogoalert")

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: ({
        if self.alertTypeColl.frame.maxY < 0 {
           self.alertTypeColl.frame.offsetInPlace(dx: 0, dy: 470)
        } else {
            self.alertTypeColl.frame.offsetInPlace(dx: 0, dy: -470)
        }

    }), completion: {
        (value: Bool) in
        print("termino!!")
      }
    )
}

@IBAction func doRedPerception(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if let usrLoc = AlertViewController.locationManager.location {
        self.x = String(usrLoc.coordinate.longitude)
        self.y = String(usrLoc.coordinate.latitude)
        self.presentViewController(pleaseWait, animated: false, completion: nil)

        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.setGeoProfile (self.tokenUser, x: String(usrLoc.coordinate.longitude), y: String(usrLoc.coordinate.latitude), username:  self.userName , geoType: "0", onCompletition: {json -> Void in

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if json["hasAccess"] == nil || json["hasAccess"]["isValid"].boolValue {
                    if let perceptionWrap = json.array {
                        self.resetVooffPreceptions()
                        self.setVooffPerceptions (perceptionWrap)
                    }
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }
                else {
                    if json["hasAccess"]["gotologin"].boolValue {
                        Functions.openLoginPage(self)
                    }
                }
             })
        })
    }
}

@IBAction func doYellowPerception(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let usrLoc = AlertViewController.locationManager.location {
        self.x = String(usrLoc.coordinate.longitude)
        self.y = String(usrLoc.coordinate.latitude)
        self.presentViewController(pleaseWait, animated: false, completion: nil)

        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.setGeoProfile (self.tokenUser, x: String(usrLoc.coordinate.longitude), y: String(usrLoc.coordinate.latitude), username:  self.userName , geoType: "1", onCompletition: {json -> Void in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if json["hasAccess"] == nil || json["hasAccess"]["isValid"].boolValue {
                    if let perceptionWrap = json.array {
                        self.resetVooffPreceptions()
                        self.setVooffPerceptions (perceptionWrap)
                    }
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }
                else {
                    if json["hasAccess"]["gotologin"].boolValue {
                        Functions.openLoginPage(self)
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
@IBAction func doGreenPerception(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let usrLoc = AlertViewController.locationManager.location {
        self.x = String(usrLoc.coordinate.longitude)
        self.y = String(usrLoc.coordinate.latitude)
        self.presentViewController(pleaseWait, animated: true, completion: nil)

        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.setGeoProfile (self.tokenUser, x: String(usrLoc.coordinate.longitude), y: String(usrLoc.coordinate.latitude), username:  self.userName , geoType: "2", onCompletition: {json -> Void in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                if json["hasAccess"] == nil || json["hasAccess"]["isValid"].boolValue {
                    if let perceptionWrap = json.array {
                        self.resetVooffPreceptions()
                        self.setVooffPerceptions (perceptionWrap)
                    }
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }
                else {
                    if json["hasAccess"]["gotologin"].boolValue {
                        Functions.openLoginPage(self)
                    }
                }
            })
        })

    }
}
func resetVooffPreceptions () {
     let geoCell :AlertViewGeoProfileCell = self.alertTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! AlertViewGeoProfileCell
     geoCell.redCount.text = "0 vooffers"
     geoCell.yellowCount.text = "0 vooffers"
     geoCell.greenCount.text = "0 vooffers"
}
func setVooffPerceptions (perceptionArr:[JSON]) {
    let geoCell :AlertViewGeoProfileCell = self.alertTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! AlertViewGeoProfileCell
    for var p in perceptionArr {
        if p["type"].stringValue == "0" {
            geoCell.redCount.text = "\(p["vooffers"].stringValue) vooffers"
        }
        else {
            if p["type"].stringValue == "1" {
                geoCell.yellowCount.text = "\(p["vooffers"].stringValue) vooffers"
            }
            else {
                if p["type"].stringValue == "2" {
                    geoCell.greenCount.text = "\(p["vooffers"].stringValue) vooffers"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let alertCell = sender as? AlertTypeCell {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? NewAlertVC
        vc?.alertType = alertCell
        if let usrLoc = AlertViewController.locationManager.location {
            vc?.location = usrLoc
        }
    } else {
        if  let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? AlertMapVC {
            if let usrLoc = AlertViewController.locationManager.location {
                vc.location = usrLoc
            }
        } else {
             print ("Cell no encontrado")
        }
    }
}
func openAlertDetail (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let userData = Functions.obtainUserData()
    let alertSB: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "AlertFriends", bundle: nil)
    if let targetAlertDetailVC = alertSB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("alertDetail") as? AlertDetailVC {
        targetAlertDetailVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
        if let alertCell = sender.view as? AlertEvidenceImg {
            let index = alertCell.indexAlertRow
            if let alertArrWrap = self.alertTable.alertsData {
                if alertArrWrap.count > 0 {
                    let alertArr = alertArrWrap[0].arrayValue
                    if alertArr.count > (index ) {
                        targetAlertDetailVC.alertData = alertArr[index]
                        targetAlertDetailVC.isCommentsTable = false

                        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getUserData(userData[vooffKeys.accessToken]!, username: userData[vooffKeys.profileUser]!, usernameToView: userData[vooffKeys.profileUser]!,  onCompletition:  { json -> Void in
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                if json["hasAccess"] == nil || json["hasAccess"]["isValid"].boolValue {
                                    targetAlertDetailVC.userProfileData = json
                                    self.showViewController(targetAlertDetailVC, sender: alertCell)
                                }
                                else {
                                    if json["hasAccess"]["gotologin"].boolValue {
                                    Functions.openLoginPage(self)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
func openAlertDetailComments(alertCell: AlertViewCell) {
     let userData = Functions.obtainUserData()
    let alertSB: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "AlertFriends", bundle: nil)
    if let targetAlertDetailVC = alertSB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("alertDetail") as? AlertDetailVC {
        targetAlertDetailVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
        let index = self.alertTable.indexPathForCell(alertCell)?.row
         if let alertArrWrap = self.alertTable.alertsData {
            if alertArrWrap.count > 0 {
                let alertArr = alertArrWrap[0].arrayValue
                if alertArr.count > (index ) {
                    targetAlertDetailVC.alertData = alertArr[index!]
                    targetAlertDetailVC.isCommentsTable = true
                    if self.alertTable.profileData == nil {
                        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getUserData(userData[vooffKeys.accessToken]!, username: userData[vooffKeys.profileUser]!, usernameToView: userData[vooffKeys.profileUser]!,  onCompletition:  { json -> Void in

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                if json["hasAccess"] == nil || json["hasAccess"]["isValid"].boolValue {
                                    targetAlertDetailVC.userProfileData = json
                                    self.showViewController(targetAlertDetailVC, sender: self)
                                }
                                else {
                                    if json["hasAccess"]["gotologin"].boolValue {
                                        Functions.openLoginPage(self)
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        })
                    } else {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            targetAlertDetailVC.userProfileData = self.alertTable.profileData![0]
                            self.showViewController(targetAlertDetailVC, sender: self)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func addUserPushToken () {
    Functions.obtainUserData()
}
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
}
```

AND this is the log Im getting:

This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.

```
 Stack:(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183142dc8 <redacted> + 148
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001827a7f80 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183142cf8 <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000183bf3b2c <redacted> + 88
    4   Foundation                          0x0000000183a74c3c <redacted> + 36
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001883a8d98 <redacted> + 64
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001883a98b0 <redacted> + 244
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000188b377f0 <redacted> + 268
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001885b4aa0 <redacted> + 176
    9   UIKit                               0x000000018829c210 <redacted> + 700
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000185c2e994 <redacted> + 148
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000185c295d0 <redacted> + 292
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000185c29490 <redacted> + 32
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000185c28ac0 <redacted> + 252
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000185c28820 <redacted> + 500
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000185c57bd4 <redacted> + 236
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182da61e0 <redacted> + 584
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182da5d58 <redacted> + 136
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182da553c pthread_mutex_lock + 0
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182da5020 start_wqthread + 4
)
```

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: I have add the code and log, thanks :)